# Prevent OkHTTP from URL encoding RequestBody

Tags: android, magento, okhttp

I am using OkHTTP to perform a call to a magento API that unfortunately seems not to be supporting url encoding.

> Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

My call is as below, how would I prevent URL encoding the  RequestBody

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("param", "some_param")
            .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();
```

Comment: You can set the URL Encoding to false in request body.

Comment: @UmangBurman mind sharing how?